# Шаблоны Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сайт на своей теме + WC. Когда я перемещаю шаблоны woocommerce в свою тему по пути woocommerce/cart/cart.php то страница корзины не загружает этот шаблон. В function.php прописывал
`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' ); function woocommerce_support() { add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' ); }`

Страница с категориями и списком товаров открываются, а страницы корзины, оформление заказа нет.

Сколько не смотрел информации ничего найти не могу. Почему тема не видит шаблоны woocommerce, перенесенные в свою тему. Но при этом если файл cart.php засунуть в корень папки темы (name_theme/cart.php) то шаблон отображается. А по пути name_theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php - нет.

Comment: Не перемещать, а копировать шаблоны в тему нужно только если хочешь их изменить. Если не работают родные WCшные - кривая у тебя тема.